# Angular switching CSS class based on route?

Tags: angularjs

I have the below HTML file:

```
<header ng-include="'app/partials/includes/header.html'"></header>

<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">

</div>
```

The above is for the login page, the below is for the register:

```
<header ng-include="'app/partials/includes/header.html'"></header>

<div class="container" ng-controller="RegisterCtrl">

</div>
```

This is the header:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Curve</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#/register">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/login">Sign In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can apply the `.active` class to the list element dependent upon the route?

If the route is /register, I want  the active class applied, and same for login.

How can this be done in Angular?

Comment: add the css inside the loading partials

Answer (score 3):

Use ng-class on any element to conditionally apply to an element.  Using the object notation the key is the class name, and the value is an expression when evaluates to true the class is added to that element's class attribute.

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="HeaderController">
  <div ng-class="{ active: registrationOrLogin }">

</div>
```

And in a controller:

```
app.controller("HeaderController", [ "$scope", "$location", function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.registrationOrLogin = $location.hash() == "/login" || $location.hash() == "/registration";
} ] );
```

Comment: Added the controller and added `ng-class="{ active: registrationOrLogin }"` to each list element.  It's not working.

Comment: It's just an example.  You'll need to adapt it to your situation.  It's important to put the controller in a parent of the elements you want to control.  I can't debug your code for you.

Comment: @BillyAssim Here's a simple working fiddle that might help you http://jsfiddle.net/ermartin86/47xfhvd4/5/